# MS Word --> WordPress exporter

Tags: microsoft-word, wordpress

Is there a tool to export advanced page make-up from MS Word to WordPress?

I need images and tables (with images in cells).

(Please don't ask me where I've got Word file that I want to convert to WordPress... :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around and it appears there's no easy answer to this.

You could save the Word documents as HTML.

Each document is going to have a folder with files in it.  You will have to load this file to your website so the HTML can link to those images (etc.)

Bottom line, lots of work, lots of finagling. Probably best to invest in Word 2007 or, if this is a one time thing, download a trial of Word 2010 and just use the wordpress upload tool. :o)

Comment: wow, Word HTML is bloated! what a bunch of junk!

Answer (score 2):

If you enable the "hidden buttons" in the editor, you'll get a "copy from word" option that'll help with some formatting.

[via](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-copy-content-from-ms-word-to-wordpress#post-568155)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Word are you running? 2007 and newer have blog integration built in.

Create a New document. In the templates dialog, choose Blog Post. You'll be led through a series of dialogs to setup the connection to your blog from there.

See this [help doc](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/blogging-with-word-2007-HA010234130.aspx?CTT=3) for more info.

Comment: No, I run Word 2003